# How to get good design on marble cake?

Tags: cake

Any pointer on how to get different marble cake patterns or zebra cake patterns?

Answer (score 3):

The basic concept is to pour your vanilla batter onto the pan and then drops of chocolate or stripes of chocolate, and then use a butter knife to swirl it. You can probably find some good demonstration videos on YouTube. Good luck!